# Free ipa errors when using SAN in certificate request

Tags: openssl, freeipa, csr

When I try to sign a CSR for a device and include the SAN ip attribute it errors with the following.
ERROR: invalid 'csr': IP address in subjectAltName (x.x.x.x) unreachable from DNS names

my IPA install is in a docker container and got a 10.88.x.x address which is not what I am using for the rest of my networks. I have multiple /24 /25 /26 networks in use for openstack and such so that each tennant is seperated etc. Is there a configuration change i need to make for ipa to accept the other networks  I use 10. 172. and 192. in my network due to having to segrigate some business traffic and network equipment.